# Current_user not being saved after login

Tags: python, flask, backend, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I made a code in Flask using Flask-Login and frontend in React. The problem I have is when I login into app, my backend works. But when I try to log out the current_user is anonymous and I can't find my mistake. I added some prints to see where my problem is and can't seem to find it.

Here is my code

```
import secrets
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user, UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
secret_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(16)
app.secret_key = secret_key

login_manager = LoginManager(app)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id_sud = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    surname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id_sud

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True
    
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

@app.route('/registration', methods=['POST'])
def registration():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()

        new_user = User(
            name=data['name'],
            surname=data['surname'],
            email=data['email']
        )

        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return jsonify({'message': 'Registration successful', 'current_user': current_user}), 201
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error while trying to register : {str(e)}')
        return jsonify({'message': 'Error while trying to register'}), 500

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()

        email = data.get('email')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if user:
            print('USER ID: ' + str(user.id_sud))
            login_user(user)
            print(current_user)
            print(current_user.is_authenticated())
            return jsonify({'message': 'Login successful'}), 200
        else:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Wrong email'}), 401

    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(f'Error while trying to log in: {str(e)}')
        return jsonify({'message': 'Error while trying to log in'}), 500
    

@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    print(current_user)
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return jsonify({'message': 'No user is currently logged in'}), 423
    try:
        logout_user()
        return jsonify({'message': 'Logged out!'}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(f'Error while logging out: {str(e)}')
        return jsonify({'message': 'Error while logging out', 'error': str(e)}), 500

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I expected the user to log in and log out without the problem. Currently, user can log in but I don't think that he is remembered and when he tries to log out, I get anonymous user. For example this is output I get for logging in:
USER ID: 19
<User 19>
True

And this is the output I get when trying to log out:

<flask_login.mixins.AnonymousUserMixin object at 0x000001E1548DE120>
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2023 12:15:03] "POST /logout HTTP/1.1" 423 -